# How to Avoid Timeout Error on Firebase Hosting Deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Sometimes I use slow internet connections to deploy to firebase hosting.

They end up with this error:

```
Task XXX failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts
```

It is possible to extend the connection timeout?
And/or the number of retries?

Thank you

Comment: if i would have been in such a situation then i would git everything and would conecct to a remote computer from where i would do all the internet heavy tasks like deploying things. while conneccting to a remote computer doesnt requre too much data and when you change a bit of code locally. again push it to your git then pulll it in your remote computer and then againn deploy things. you can buy a compute engine for very less amount or even free if you a new gmail. GCP gives you $300 for testing out everything. so do it that way i do it a lot.

Comment: It's not a heavy task. Just uploading the files for hosting. The same as uploading the source files to a repository. 
But I understood the idea, thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Usually that error goes away after some time from my experience. You can add --debug to the deploy command to get more information: eg. `firebase deploy --project xxx --debug`.

Comment: What happens is the deploy continues from where it left of. 
For example on the first try uploads from file 1 to file 80, on second try uploads from file 80 to file 150, and finally he upload the final files from 150 to 170. This is an example.
This is some timeout firebase has and when the connection is slow and there's many files the timeout is reached and the operation is aborted from firebase side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible at present.

However, you can open an issue in the `firebase-tools` GitHub repo, explaining your problem and requesting this functionality: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Edit: workarounds

User @example had an interesting work around in a comment (paraphrased):

> connect to a remote computer to do all the internet heavy tasks like deploying things. 1. Change code locally, 2. push to your git, then 3. pull, it in your remote computer and 4. deploy.   1, 2, 3 are low data, and the remote handles 4., the high-data task

And as an alternative, you could set up a GitHub action to deploy on push to master: here's a post describing that workflow https://fireship.io/snippets/github-actions-deploy-angular-to-firebase-hosting/

Comment: I'm always using new internet connections and this only happens in some rare ocasions. I hoped for a direct solution.
Thank you for your input and suggestions. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Does your firebase project contain other things like functions that are also being deployed? If so, you might want to consider deploying the hosting part independently using:

`firebase deploy --only hosting`

If the issue really is your connection speed though, I don't think there is a connection timeout that you can alter. My suggestion would be to commit your code to a cloud git repository and deploy directly from there using something like GitHub Actions or GitLab CI/CD.

Comment: Yes, it's the connection speed, I always using different internet connections, and this only happens when the connection is slow. I already deploy only hosting.

Thank you for your input. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, uploading only one file for example index.html and firebase uploaded it. After i tried to upload normally with more files like 1600 and firebase uploaded those without a problem.

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more useful if you also included an example of a command to upload only one file.

Answer (score 0):

Best remedy I have found so far...

When you encounter this issue, YES it has to do with choppy internet connection, it pretty much has happened late at night.

DELETE last added folder and re-upload smaller chunks of files.

Deleting cache folder will NOT always work.

Reverting firebase cli to previous version temporally may help.